# Using shared memory (VRAM + RAM) for visualisation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I'm trying to visualise 500 images in `tensorboard`, but I keep getting the OOM error. The issue seems to be that I don't have enough VRAM for a 500 x `HEIGHT` x `WIDTH` numpy array. Here's the code:

```py
images_with_boxes = tf.Variable(  initial_value = np.zeros((cfg.VISUALIZATION_BATCH_SIZE, cfg.IMAGE_HEIGHT, cfg.IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)), name="image", dtype=tf.float32)
update_placeholder = tf.placeholder(images_with_boxes.dtype, shape=images_with_boxes.get_shape())
update_images = images_with_boxes.assign(update_placeholder)

tf.summary.image("images", images_with_boxes, max_outputs=cfg.VISUALIZATION_BATCH_SIZE )
```

where `cfg.VISUALIZATION_BATCH_SIZE` is 500.

I see ```cfg.VISUALIZATION_BATCH_SIZE`` is often set to 16, but I need 500 samples visualised. Is there any way to increase memory space for the numpy array? Perhaps by sharing RAM?

Any thought appreciated.